# Auto layout constraint breaks when resizing view dynamically (dragging motion)

Tags: ios, resize, autolayout, constraints

I have a view that is sandwiched between two other views, and the height of the middle view can be changed through pan gesture.

I'm using a gesture recognizer to get the location of touch and feeding the value to the middle view's height constraint to make it dynamically resizable.

One issue is when the touch location goes beyond the middle view's bounds and overlaps with either the top view or the bottom view, I get the warning:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints ...
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

This hasn't really caused any real issues but just in case it might cause a big problem, I'd like to know if

a) it's correct to use the height constraint to dynamically change the height
b) there is any way to avoid getting that warning logged

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the entire error output from the constraints? Maybe during your resizing, the size gets to be less than zero and that's why it's crashing

Comment: The resizing does get a negative value. The app doesn't crash, but I just get a warning and I'm worried it might cause unexpected problems. I get the warnings on two occasions: when the height constraint's constant value is a negative and when it causes the bottom view's height to become negative. But the user should be able to resize in anyway, so do I just run with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

a) Yes, this is the correct way to update the height of the view

b) Yes, there is a way to get rid of the warnings

Since your view gets negative values for the height constraints, you could add a check for the height so that you never set a negative value to it. Then, you won't have the error log anymore.

Not sure if you are supporting iOS 7 also, but if you are, the app will most probably crash because of the layout errors.

So, my suggestion would be to add something like this, to where you are updating the constraints:

```
[self.heightConstraint setConstant:MAX(0, value)];
```

Good luck with your project!